# Gatsby Build Fails with "Reading from 'node:crypto' is not handled by plugins" but Development Build Works Fine

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, gatsby, wagmi

I'm currently working on a Gatsby project using TypeScript, and I've encountered an issue during the build process (yarn build). The error message I receive is:

> Reading from "node:crypto" is not handled by plugins (Unhandled scheme).
> Webpack supports "data:" and "file:" URIs by default.
> You may need an additional plugin to handle "node:" URIs.
> not finished Building HTML renderer - 8.371s
> error Command failed with exit code 1.

The strange part is that the development server (yarn start) runs without any issues, but the production build fails with the above error. Meaning the SSR fails.

Recently I updated my wagmi package to latest and it's since then the error started occurring. - This is the cause and I've tested it.

Things I've Tried:

1. Adding a custom Webpack configuration to shim the crypto module with
   crypto-browserify.
2. Checking for Node-specific modules or
   browser-specific APIs that might cause SSR issues.
3. Clearing cache
   and public directories.
4. Updating all dependencies and plugins to
   their latest versions.
5. Ensuring there are no conflicting versions or
   incompatible dependencies.

Has anyone encountered this issue before or have any suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve it? I appreciate any insights you may provide.

Gatsby Version: 5.11.0
Node Version: 19.1.0
Wagmi Version: 1.3.10

Answer (score 2):

Found this issue and it worked for me.

https://github.com/sindresorhus/md5-hex/issues/17

```
  new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(/node:/, (resource) => {
        resource.request = resource.request.replace(/^node:/, "");
      })
```

In gatsby, for some reason the webcrypto library wasn't getting link by using just using the webpack.fallback["crypto"] =require("crypto-browserify")

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ actions, getConfig }) => {
    const config = getConfig()
    if (config.externals && config.externals[0]) {
        config.externals[0]["node:crypto"] = require.resolve('crypto-browserify')
    }
    actions.replaceWebpackConfig(config)
}
```

Comment: This worked for me too! I've been looking for this answer for a long time, thanks Christian!

Comment: @Mehmet Önder I updated the answer, as I found some crypto functions didn't work in the build. There's a whole discussion about it in that linked github issue